# Mac / iOS Packet Assassin: NSURLErrorDomain -1005 “The network connection was lost.”

Tags: ios, django, xcode, macos, alamofire

I am testing an Alamofire / Swift based Rest API code against a Django Rest Framework backend, and am seeing the dreaded: `NSURLErrorDomain -1005` error.  On the server side, logs show an error code of 499, client disconnected.

Now for the interesting parts.  This only seems to happen on a get request to one of the resources - ie it works for three resources, but not for a fourth, but the server dev says there is nothing special about that end point. I am running from XCTests, both on the device, and on the simulator.  I have have tried it from two dev machines, one in my office, and one in a random coffee shop.  I have also ported my framework based API to Mac, and run it from an OSX based test suite.  At this point it is getting a little nutty, so I thought I would put it into the aether for the keen reader.  ;-)

I have read the other posts on SO relating to -1005, but the bulk of those related to rebooting the simulator.  I have also wiped my WIFI settings and per above, tried multiple machines.  In fact, this was also validated on a third machine by a second developer.

I would like to figure out what I could trap in Xcode, to figure out the source of the error or otherwise get more data.  It's not throwing an exception per se, so I can't use symbolic breakpoints that way.

I should also mention that all my code funnels through the same logic, I have essentially a set of generic REST base functions that create concrete (but generic) model objects, and the rest of the API is just an explicit layer (`fun getFoo(...) -> [Foo]`, `fun getBar(...) -> [Bar]`, for the sake of pre Xcode 7 Obj-C compatibility (support for generics).  In short though, all the high level API calls cleanly funnel through the same core set of REST functions.

I almost forget one other key point, when I test with the Alamofire generated curl request, that does in fact return valid data.  (It would appear that my only sane option is to reconstruct the problematic get without Alamofire and go from there.)

Comment: I am also having this issue, but only in ONE of my three environments. I suspect that the issue is on the Django end, not on the iOS end

Comment: I wish I could remember what this was, I think we had to dig into the bowels of the Django logging to figure it out.  I think the server was kicking the client off, and mis-reporting it though.